# neo4j-go-driver force to abort long running query

Tags: go, neo4j

I have several neo4j Cypher queries on my backend application. In rare circumstances, one of the queries takes too long to complete (due to an unoptimized query I guess), and not only that, it also cost the server resource usage spiking really high.

I am currently working with Go programming, I use the official neo4j-go-driver.

Is there any way to terminate a long-running query using the driver? from the driver's doc I found this API [WithTxTimeout](https://godoc.org/github.com/neo4j/neo4j-go-driver/neo4j#WithTxTimeout). However, I am not sure what the API does, whether it merely ignores the long-running query on the surface or actually terminates it.

Really need the help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it should terminate it.
The code should look something like this (replace `ReadTransaction` by `WriteTransaction` depending on the query):

```golang
query := "MATCH (n) RETURN n"
timeout := 30 * time.Second
result, err := session.ReadTransaction(func(tx neo4j.Transaction) (interface{}, error) {
    result, err := tx.Run(query, map[string]interface{}{})
    // do something interesting
}, neo4j.WithTxTimeout(timeout))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set transaction timeout from the server as well to some value, by default it is disabled:

```
 neo4j> CALL dbms.setConfigValue('dbms.transaction.timeout', '360s') ;
```

Comment: I don't have the privilege to modify neo4j server configuration. but thank you for the answer